# Android: UI elements overflow the screen in lower resolution devices

Tags: android, user-interface, overflow, element

I'm going crazy with this issue. I'm designing an App and testing it in two different devices, one with 1280x720p resolution and other with 320x480p.

480p device always overflows the UI content (height), making it impossible to use the App... How can I prevent this? I'm using a RelativeLayout as global container.

Examples:
[image]

Comment: Can't you just put your relative layout (root layout) into a ScrollView or is there a restriction around using that? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: The problem of ScrollView is that it affects to button elements, making them laggy. I'm looking for a solution for Relative Layout. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say 'it affects to button elements', I haven't had that issue myself, give it a try it may not be the ScrollView that was causing the lag

Comment: ScrollViews affect Buttons' responsivity. Try it, it makes the "pressable" elements have a delay (about 0.5 seconds) due to the scroll functionality. I tried ScrollView before and it solved the overflow issue but I'm looking for another solution, if there is one..., avoiding the delay in ScrollView. Thanks for answering mate.

Comment: I've tried as you said, with a ScrollView my buttons respond near instantly < 50 ms to show the depressed image and with a none ScrollView they occur the same, this is on an old 2.3.5 device. It may well be that it's not the ScrollView that was causing your lag, the Android Profiler works really well at isolating performance problems, so it may be worth using that: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this developer guide for [Supporting Screensizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html). If you want an easy fix, you could wrap the layout in a list, you could wrap your layout in a scrollview.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Or you could define different dimensions or layouts in the resources of your project. For example, I'm writing a project for a device that comes in 3 main sizes, so I have

```
res
 > layout
  > values
  > values-sw480dp
  > values-sw600dp
```

I define my hard values in the dimen.xml of each folder. In the layout, I can use one definition, and it'll find the correct value to use.